# How to use dragenter to swap images

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop

I have a page full of about 42 images and I need to be able to pick an image and drag it. When I drag it over another image, it needs to swap the image it just went over with the image it is currently over.

So far it works in the sense of dragging and swapping but when I drag it over a new image it swaps it with the very first image I selected. I hope that makes sense! If not, I can try to explain more clearly. Here is what I have in my script portion:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
             .normalImage {
                width: 225px;
                height: 115px;
            }
        </style>
       <script>
          var currentImage;
          var temp;

        function setup(){
            document.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
            document.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
            var allImages = document.images;
            for(var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++){
                allImages[i].className = "normalImage";
                allImages[i].addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnterHandler);
                //allImages[i].addEventListener("dragover", dragOverHandler);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', (event) =>{
            setup();
        });

        function dragStart(event){
            currentImage = event.target;

        }

        function dragEnd(event){
            var construction = document.getElementById("construction");
            if(event.target == construction){
                construction.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
            }
        }

        function allowDrop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function dragOverHandler(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function dragEnterHandler(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            temp = currentImage.src;
            currentImage.src = event.target.src;
            event.target.src = temp;
            previous = event.target.src;
            // currentImage.src = event.target.src; changes everything to start picture
            console.log(event);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image01.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image02.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image03.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image04.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image05.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image06.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image07.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image08.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image09.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image10.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image11.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image12.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image13.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image14.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image15.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image16.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image17.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image18.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image19.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image20.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image21.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image01.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image02.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image03.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image04.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image05.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image06.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image07.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image08.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image09.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image10.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image11.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image12.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image13.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image14.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/Image15.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image16.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image17.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image18.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image19.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image20.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="images/Image21.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code including the html container?

Comment: Sure thing! I just edited the post!

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm just a little unsure what you want to achieve. ;) Let's say you start dragging Image01.jpg - what should happen if you drag it over Image02.jpg? What happens if you finally drag this over Image03.jpg?

Comment: If I drag Image01.jpg over Image02.jpg then they should swap. If I continue to drag Image01.jpg over Image03.jpg then those should then swap. Leaving Image02.jpg in the spot where Image01.jpg originally was; Image03.jpg  should be where Image02.jpg originally was; and finally Image01.jpg should be where Image03.jpg originally was. Hope that made sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback function for the drageenter event you need to store references to the target image, the previous image & it's source and swap them accordingly.
Replace your dragEnterHandler() function with this:

```
function dragEnterHandler(event)
{
    if(currentImage!=event.target)
    {
        var newSrc=event.target.src;
        var oldImage=currentImage;

        event.target.src=oldImage.src;
        oldImage.src=newSrc;
        currentImage=event.target;
    }
}
```